# Jenkins post-build action save error

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins project configuration I'm trying to add a post-build action to send emails to a specific email after every build.

I add the E-mail Notification post-build action and after entering the recipients I click save. After clicking save Jenkins gives an error saying `A problem occurred while processing the request.` Below that is a massive stack trace.

I just checked and whenever I make changes to my other post-build actions and click save I have the same issue. Now when I make changes to like the description for example it gives the same error but seems to save my changes.

I have installed the following plugins. Not sure of one of these is causing the issue.

- GitHub Plugin
- Clover Plugin
- Checkstyle Plug-in
- TAP Plugin
- Embeddable Build Status Plugin
- NodeJS Plugin
- GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin

Any ideas on how I can fix this error? Basically my end goal is to enable an e-mail notification post-build action but it seems to be more widespread in terms of saving project configuration. Let me know if there is any other information or details I can provide.

Comment: The stack trace will be helpful for answering your question.

Comment: @AlexO I realized that their was a Jenkins update I hadn't installed. After installing that it seems to work. Of course it's super early and I haven't played with it a ton but at first glance updating Jenkins seems to have worked. For some reason the NodeJS plugin doesn't work but that is a totally different issue. Thanks anyways tho.

Answer (score 1):

Since my reputation is too low to write a comment with some follow-up questions, based on the amount of information you provided, your problems might be connected to the following:

- reloading configuration from disk - this is not the best thing to do. If you made direct changes to Jenkins files, it's best to restart Jenkins, otherwise problems like this might randomly occur (another thing that sometimes happens is [executors suddenly dying](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29902))
- wrong file permissions - I would check, just in case, if the Jenkins user has write permissions to all files.
- (unlikely) installing a plugin in a non-standard way (for example without restarting Jenkins?)

I hope this was useful.

Comment: Thanks so much. I realized there was an update to Jenkins. Updating it at first glance seems to have worked. Of course I'm not 100% sure since I haven't played around with it a ton. Hopefully that was the issue tho. For some reason the NodeJS plugin doesn't seem to work on the new update but that it totally different. Thanks again.